# How to limit usb 2.0 port to work as usb 1.1 in ubuntu?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, usb, printer, bsod

Ive got problem with kvm usb forwarding and printing (windows xp guest goes BSOD when i try to print something). Ive been adviced to change usb to 1.1 version. That only kvm works with 1.1 not 2.0 version of usb. How can i do this for certain port in ubuntu os?

USB device -> Canon LBP 2900 (witch need to be network printer) directly connected to Ubuntu server with qemu-kvm via USB. This printer works horribly in ubuntu. So i've created guest vm  with winxp and forwarded there usb port. Winxp recognize this printer and installs drivers. When trying to print test page -- BSOD. In VirtualBox all works fine.

It looks like system detects printer as usb2.0 device, but kvn forwards only usb1.1 max. So i need to change usb 2.0 to 1.1

**lsusb  | grep  Canon**

```
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 04a9:2676 Canon, Inc. CAPT Device
```

**uname -r**

```
3.2.0-27-generic-pae
```

**lsb_release -r**

```
Release:    12.04
```

**cpuinfo**

```
model: AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 4200+
flags: svm
```

**dmesg on printers connect**

```
[216143.260035] usb 2-7: reset high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci_hcd
[216143.800036] usb 2-7: reset high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci_hcd
[216219.096159] usb 2-7: USB disconnect, device number 8
[216221.100042] usb 2-7: new high-speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
[216341.670533] usb 2-7: USB disconnect, device number 10
[216342.808034] usb 2-7: new high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci_hcd
```

**Windows guest system BSOD:**

```
will be updated
```

**dmesg after sending test page** pritner shows like disconnected. No BSOD for now.

```
[217940.556048] usb 2-7: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci_hcd
[217941.124034] usb 2-7: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci_hcd
[218069.198088] usb 2-7: usbfs: process 14070 (kvm) did not claim interface 0 before use
[218070.198916] usb 2-7: usbfs: process 14070 (kvm) did not claim interface 0 before use
last message -- 20+ times
```

Comment: Can you provide some details of exactly what the problem is that you're having?

Comment: Really, more details. Including but not limited to: Ubuntu version; What BSOD you got from Windows; and what you REALLY want to do with this printer.

Answer (score 1):

libvirt has supported USB 2 for a while now: http://www.linux-kvm.com/content/virt-manager-adds-support-usb2  I'd recommend upgrading.

Comment: Not to mention they just announced [USB 3.0 support](http://www.linux-kvm.com/content/qemu-kvm-11-adds-experimental-support-usb-30).